# javascript onmouse hover event?

Tags: javascript, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript trigger onmouseover event progrmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228376/javascript-trigger-onmouseover-event-progrmatically)

how to call onmouse over event in function