# Raise a mousemove event on an element

Tags: javascript, events

So I have an element `var element = document.getElementById("myele")` and  I would like to call its `onmousemove` event handler manually.

I have tried the following, but got an error that it is not a function:

```
element.onmousemove()
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: The confusion you've suffered is thinking that the event is called "onmousemove". It's not; it's called "mousemove". But some syntax prepends the "on" in order to provide access to that event handler. Silly DOM!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger onmouseover event programatically in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228376/trigger-onmouseover-event-programatically-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

....

To call the `mousemove` event on an element remove the `on`

```
element.mousemove()
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The OP edited their question to show what they did within the grace period to show was they tried. I am answering based on what they tried.

Comment: You're right - it's better now. And now that you have removed your comment, answering makes more sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry about that :-\

Comment: No, I am - I missed the edit

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sok we are all good :-D No harm done (yet)

Comment: Bad news - the hunter killer drones are already out of control range, and I can't turn them back. I'm so sorry.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oooooh crud.... There must be a self-destruct mechanism somewhere....

Comment: If you can intercept the missile then you can sort of climb up on to the casing, pry open the control circuitry and sever the red wire... but by that point it's usually too late. ... Hello? Are you there...?

Comment: Hmmmmm **WHICH RED WIRE?!?** I see two of them! Help! I only have like 13 more seconds @LightnessRacesinOrbit !!

Comment: ..... Oops. Goodbye, @Neal.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [I'll be back.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1ypn0y32Ac)