# React manually fire mouseover event

Tags: reactjs

Is there anyway to trigger React's mouseover and mouseenter event? It's possible to fire:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(someNode).focus();
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(someNode).click();
```

Is there a similar way to fire mouseenter? I need to do a complicated React event with a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 4):

From @Jonathan's answer in this question: [Trigger onmouseover event programmatically in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228376/trigger-onmouseover-event-programmatically-in-javascript)

This worked for me:

```
function fireEvent(elementId, eventName) {
  if(document.getElementById(elementId) != null) {   
    if(document.getElementById(elementId).fireEvent) {
      document.getElementById(elementId).fireEvent('on' + eventName);     
    } else {   
      var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
      evObj.initEvent(eventName, true, false);
      document.getElementById(elementId).dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
fireEvent(elementId, "mouseover");
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using the [React Synthetic Events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events)? Here's an example:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  onEnter() {
        console.log('enter');  
  }

  onOver() {
        console.log('over');  
  }

    render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', padding: '20px' }} onMouseOver={this.onOver}>
          <h1 onMouseEnter={this.onEnter}>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('mainContainer'));
```

And here's the [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ickyrr/48poaoog/) for the above code.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. As I mentioned above, I'm getting the element using ReactDOM.findDOMNode and I need to trigger an event. What you are doing is adding an event listener only.