# How to open a <select /> via label, ::before, or programatically?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

Any solution need only work in WebKit browsers.

The internet is littered with attempts to make this work - some who claim to have it working and some who claim it can't be done. In my experience, none of the suggested methods have worked. Is this simply impossible?

Supposing I have a select like `<select id="mySelect" />`

**Things I've tried:**

- `select::before` -- Is added to the DOM, but doesn't render
- `<label for="mySelect" />` -- Does nothing when clicked/tapped
- `document.querySelector('select').click()` -- Does nothing
- [The method from this answer (React-specific)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878231/6025788) -- Cannot assign a `click` handler or any other handler that can programmatically open the `select` to begin with

I'm open even to a jQuery solution, even though we're using React and we would be loading jQuery *solely* for triggering the `select` to open.

**On third party select components:** The goal is to trigger the mobile OS's native select control for the user, so something like React-Select is not suitable.

Comment: There used to be ways of opening a select programmatically, but I believe they have all been removed from modern browsers. There's currently no way to open a select without the user actually clicking on it

Comment: You could always go a different route. Either create your own or use a third party plugin to convert the select to a list for a "pretty select" or whatever you want to call it. After that its been converted, its now a div or something similar when can be controlled and opened via javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due). Do note the most upvoted comment on [the answer that claims it is possible in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due#comment66764357_10136523) that mentions it was deprecated in Chrome 53...

Answer (score 0):

A dirty solution updated from here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/249219/3684265)

```js
var _select = document.getElementById("test");

_select.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
  this.size = 1;
});

_select.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
  this.size = 4;//set to show the number that you want
});
```

```html
<select id="test">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="1">3</option>
  <option value="1">4</option>
  <option value="1">5</option>
  <option value="1">6</option>
</select>
```

---