# JS convert onclick() to mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I'm having an issue with a piece of JS that doesn't seem to want to work.

I created a tab widget, following this guide:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

I replaced onclick with onmouseover in the html part and changed the buttons to a-type elements:

**Original:**

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
```

**My version:**

```
<a class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCompany(event, 'xName') "id="defaultOpen">Link</a>
```

Now that's all working fine. But further down the page it explains how to keep a certain tab open by default but it doesn't seem to be working alright. Neither in the original nor in my version.

**Original:**

```
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

**My version:**

```
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").mouseover();
```

Has anyone got an idea why this wouldn't work? It's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228376/trigger-onmouseover-event-programatically-in-javascript)

Just use

```
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").onmouseover();
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").mouseover();
```

```js
function click_btn()
{
  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").onmouseover();
}

function openCompany(a, b)
{
  alert('link');
}
```

```html
<button class="tablinks" onclick="click_btn()" id="defaultOpenButton">London</button>
<a class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCompany(event, 'xName')" id="defaultOpen">Link</a>
```

Comment: Ooh, yeah. It looks like `.mouseover()` is only defined for [jQuery.](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

Comment: Yes. And If you are going to use JQuery, you can also use something like `$("#defaultOpen").trigger("mouseover");`

Answer (score -1):

Can you use just this line to keep the first one open :

```
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").style.display = "inline";
```

[Demo](http://viahold.com/1GhG)

I think this can help you

Comment: While that may work, being able to trigger the mouseover event is a fundamental thing that we should learn how to do, rather than try to work-around.