# Vanilla JavaScript: How to stand (hover) on an object?

Tags: javascript

Say you have an html object that when you stand on (with the mouse), a menu gets opened.

You don't have to click anything, you just move the mouse on top of that HTML element (to hover on it), then just about the end of your mouse cursor, a menu will be opened.

A *mouseover* possible result.

### My question

If I have the element's CSS selector and I targeted this way:

```
document.querySelector('.myElement');
```

How could I **emulate** a mouseover?

Out of curiosity tried this:

document.querySelector('.myElement').mouseover();

but I got:

> TypeError: document.querySelector(...).mouseover is not a function

I expected something like this because I always saw people using `click()` but not `mouseover()`.

Maybe I should just do addEventListener();

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent and also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Only a handful of events have methods defined – [`HTMLElement` Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement#Methods).

Comment: Related: [Trigger onmouseover event programmatically in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13655046)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger onmouseover event programmatically in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228376/trigger-onmouseover-event-programmatically-in-javascript)

Comment: Why don’t you use a :hover in css instead? Very unlikely you need javascript for this.

Comment: ^ best non-answer. This is really how it should be handled.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="mydiv" onmouseover="yourFunctionOne" onmouseout="yourFunctionTwo" />
```

How about this?

Comment: This implies some other rework necessary, but would still only work if the hover menu were JavaScript based. If the hover menu were CSS based this would not work

Comment: @Xufox foo and bar are used to represent the functions.

Comment: @mlhDev The question title says Vanilla Javascript.

Comment: @Abhijeet If `yourFunctionOne` and `yourFunctionTwo` are function names, then this code won’t do anything.