# React - how to manually trigger mouseenter of child component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design, mouseevent

I am using ReactJS and Google's Material components for the web using RMWC (https://github.com/jamesmfriedman/rmwc).
I have a parent component which contains an icon and a text under it.
This icon has Material Design Ripples effect on it, which means that when I hover it or click it, an animation is triggered.

I would now like to trigger that same effect when I hover or click on the text that is under.

Here is the component:

```
export class Subject extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

triggerRippleHover() {
    console.log("hovered");
    // HERE
  }

renderSubjectIcon(Icon) {
    return (
        <Icon className="subject-icon" />
    )
  }

render() {
    return (
        <div className="subject-container">
            <Ripple unbounded>
                <div className="subject-icon-container">
                    {this.renderSubjectIcon(this.props.icon)}
                </div>
            </Ripple>
            <span onMouseEnter={this.triggerRippleHover}>{this.props.name}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Basically, I just want to "extend" the zone that triggers the behavior of the icon (if that makes any sense).

I have been searching extensively but haven't been able to find an appropriate  answer.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: May be better to find css that makes that effect and add it in you stylesheet?

Comment: Indeed, that could be great, but I need that effect to only be shown on the icon, not the text. (Or maybe I misunderstood your answer ?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

1.Get the `<Icon />` **ref** as follow ([refs documented here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)):

```
<Icon className="subject-icon" ref={element => this.iconRef = element} />
```

2.Once you have the `<Icon />` **ref**, then in your `triggerRippleHover` callback, you can programatically trigger `mouseover` event (or the corresponding one) to the `this.iconRef`. [Here's another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13655046/4312466), that describes better how to trigger the event. Here's an example code snippet, that will give you insight about my idea:

```
triggerRippleHover() {
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent
  const event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  })

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent  
  this.iconRef.dispatchEvent(event)
}
```

Comment: Work for me!!! I was trying to manually trigger `mouseover` while writing a test with mocha. Thanks a lot, you save me day!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MDN article on how to trigger events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

One approach could be the following:

```
var mouseoverEvent = new Event('mouseover');

myTrigger.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    myMouseOver.dispatchEvent(mouseoverEvent);
});
```

Here is the full fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/sarawinter79/sc2fzeqm/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a alot for your answers, they have been helpful, I have managed to simulate the onMouseDown and onMouseUp events thanks to Jordan Enev answer (By triggering the activate() API of the ripples effect https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-ripple) but not the hover, because there isn't any API for that.

I now realize that I need to  trigger the :hover pseudo class of the Material Component, which seems not doable with the method.