# Simulating/Call a .mouseover event with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, mouseover

I would like a mouseover event happening on a css selector while the mouse curser is on a different element. I need to set this up through a custom tag in Google Tag Manager running a js. My idea was:

```
(function() {   
document.getElementById("atcclick").mouseover();
})();
```

When I use `.click` a click on #atcclick is recognized, works perfectly fine! But with `.mouseover` no mouseover event is recognized. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228376/trigger-onmouseover-event-programmatically-in-javascript but I do not think it is going to trigger CSS.

Comment: You would be better off setting up styles and adding a class to trigger the same css.

Comment: Found the answer in the link you sent (see below). Works Like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Oke thanks to epascarello I got it, this is working:

```
(function() {   
document.getElementById('atcclick').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', { 'view': window, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true }));
})();
```

Comment: You'll want to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` since `mouseover` will affect child nodes.

Answer (score -1):

`You should use .onmouseover() method instead of .mouseover()`.

Do something like -

```js
(function() {   
document.getElementById("atcclick").onmouseover = function(){ console.log('on mouseover event')};
})();
```

```html
<p id="atcclick">This is demo text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply Vibhooti. Unfortunately the suggestion doesn’t work. .onmouseover cannot be called really, can it? I need to call a mouseover event on a css selector (triggered by a js script). While the actual mouse curser is on a different element.

Comment: It would be like `.onmouseover(EventObjectHere)`, but you would still need to pass in the `EventObject`, so you'll want to do the `.dispatchEvent` way. Your example assigns the Event, but doesn't fire it unless a mouseover occurs.