# How to programmatically hover the item and click button in js

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the [demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/4jhxe0wc/) 
Note: This demo is static in reality there will be dynamic list and button functionality.

On hover of item two buttons are showing.

**Problem**:
I want to programmatically hover each of the items and click on button using JS. This is a third party website UI demo and I want to handle it using my Chrome's console tab, if that's possible.

**CSS:**

```
.row .actions {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 44px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 2px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="list">
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
   <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#list li").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).append('<button id="but1" onclick="button1()">Button1</button>' +
            '<button id="but2" onclick="button2()">Button2</button>');
    },
    function() {
        $('#but1').remove();
        $('#but2').remove();
    });
    
    function button1(){ console.log("button1") }
    
     function button2(){ console.log("button2") }
```

Comment: this might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228376/trigger-onmouseover-event-programmatically-in-javascript

Comment: @JaromandaX it's worth saying that also in chrome, when you select an element through the dom inspector, you can use it in console as `$0`

Comment: @diegod did not know that - just realised, not going to help anyway - you can't "programatically" hover an element to get those buttons to show - so, I think the OP is out of luck

Comment: you are partly right.. I mean there's not specifically the "hover" event so you can't dispatch it. The css counterpart `:hover`, as far as I read around, requires you to dispatch the mouseenter event to the element. It isn't that far from a solution after all. The `$0` strategy is something I found out not very long ago and was a big surprise to see. It's sad to say that js-wise I still think chrome is another planet. I force myself using firefox as much as I can but sometimes it's really a pain (for me)

Comment: If the site embeds jQuery, you should be able to use it on the console as well. `$('whatever-selects-the-element').trigger('mouseover')` should do the trick.

Comment: @CBroe after mouseover, whatever button it shows i want to click on it using js. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, just select it within the context of the element you just "hovered."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
$("#list li").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).append('<button id="but1" onclick="button1()">Button1</button>' +
      '<button id="but2" onclick="button2()">Button2</button>');
  },
  function() {
    $('#but1').remove();
    $('#but2').remove();
  });

function button1(item) {
  console.log("button1")
}

function button2(item) {
  console.log("button2")
}

async function autoHoverAndClick() {
  for await (item of Array.from($("#list li"))) {
    await new Promise((res) => {
      item.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseover'));
      $('#but1').click();
      $('#but2').click();
      console.log("------------------")
      setTimeout(() => {
        item.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseout'));
        res()
      }, 1500)
    })
  }

}

(async() => await autoHoverAndClick())()
```

```css
.row .actions {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 44px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```